# Include # (commented lines) while using awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, scripting

So I have a file say abc with the content :

```
 Post=76.34.34
 Pull=56.76.34
 # In case you're not a regular user then post 76.34.36/37,
 # change the value to (1.1.1,)
 Number=506442
```

I need to make an awk command from this using each line to compare it elsewhere.

So I'm using

```
awk '/Post=76.34.34/ && /Pull=56.76.34/ && /# In case you're not a regular user then post 76.34.36/37,/ && /# change the value to (1.1.1,)/ && /Number=506442/' /File/ToBe/Compared
```

The issue here is coming because of the #. For characters like #, **'** (incase of **you're**) how does once proceed? Need to use this awk command to compare just these lines and then match it in a file.

Need to know how to include #, ' in such a case.

Comment: Those tests cannot all return true. They only test a single line. Do you want to test successive lines? Why do you think the `#` is a problem here? Can you more clearly explain what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: So basically this file has certain configurations and the data gets changed at times after certain operations. I am hardcoding these lines in an awk statement and if in case the data does change, then I shall simply append the original data back into this file. 
So

`awk '/Post.............../File/Path
if [ $? != 0 ]
truncate -s 0 /File/Path
echo "Original Data"`

Comment: Why bother checking at all? Why not just always re-create with the original data? (That being said why is it changing in the first place?)

Answer (score 0):

`#` in a pattern or string shouldn't cause any problem:

```
$ echo "# hello" | awk '/^#/ { print $2 }'
hello
```

The single quote is a bit more of a pain because we normally enclose our awk in-line commands with single quotes. Different people have different favorite ways of dealing with this.

> Use `\x27`

```
$ echo "you're welcome" | awk '/you\x27re/ { print $2 }'
welcome
```

> Put your awk script in a file

```
$ cat foo.awk
/you're/ { print $2 }

$ echo "you're welcome" | awk -f foo.awk
welcome
```

> Surround the in-line script with double quotes and escape as necessary (I would save this method for only the most trivial cases, or maybe never).

```
$ echo "you're welcome" | awk "/you're/ { print \$2 }"
welcome
```